# How do I add one more loop to this?

Tags: python, loops

Part of my code is:

```
list1 = zeros((x,y))

for j in range(1,y):
    for i in range(1, x-1):
        list1[i,j] = list1[i,j-1] + Equation
```

This works fine. However, when I want to get to the next stage, I need to modify the "Equation" part in the second for loop. Say the equation is `(a*b+c)*d`, I wish to make one of the `parameters(a,b,c,d)` varying with every increase in `j`.

That is, when `j` is 1, `a = something`. When `j` increases to 2, a changes according. It is like a is function of `j`. For example: `a = A*cos(w*j)`.

My problem is, how do I loop this relation into the code so that `a` will be updated every time?

Comment: update `a` and then update `list1`...

Answer (score 1):

Just add an expression in the outer loop, calculating `a` based on the changing value of `j`:

```
for j in range(1, y):
    a = A * cos(w * j)
    for i in range(1, x-1):
        list1[i, j] = list1[i, j - 1] + (a * b + c) * d
```

Comment: So simple? Thanks! I have another question: what if a depends not on j, but I want to say a += 0.001 for every increase in j?

Comment: @sopho-J: then just do that. Set `a = starting_value` outside of the loops, and increment `a` in the outer loop so that it varies with `j`. Or make it a function of `j`, `a = starting_value + (j * 0.001)` would give you the same value.